# Rails list all images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to list all images in a certain folder, based on the iteration.

In my controller I declared something similar to this

```
@styles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

And render it in the view with

```
<% @styles.each do |s| %><div>
  <%= s %>
<% end %>
```

Each `@styles` got its own directory, for instance: `app/assets/images/styles/one/` with several SVG files in it.

Now I want to render all SVG files in each folder inside a separate `div`. Something like

```
@stylesExample = Dir.glob('app/assets/images/styles/**/*.svg')
```

with the view

```
<% @stylesExample.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag "#{image.split('/')}/#{s}/" %>
<% end %>
```

This obviously doesn't work. What would be the best way to pass in a variable in a controller action to list all the SVGs?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you need to choose which index of the `.split` you want interpolated into your string,and reverse the order of the parts as well? Like `"styles/#{s}/#{image.split('/')[-1]}"`?

Comment: Nope, prints all SVGs in every ``div``

Comment: and sorry - can you show us the entire ruby code that produces this as well?